Existence of the derivative of a convolution
I'm studying a book on functional analysis that has the following theorem. The book does not provide a proof, only some arguments that the theorem is a consequence of theorems on continuity and differentiability under the integral sign.

Theorem. If $f \in L^r (\mathbb{R})$, with $1\leq r < \infty$, and $g \in C_c^{k}(\mathbb{R})$, then $f *   g$ is k-times continuously differentiable and $(f * g)^{(k)} = f * g^{(k)}$.

My question is if the derivative of the convolution is indeed a derivative in the classical sense, as it is not specified in the book and weak derivatives are only introduced in later chapters.
Assuming $f$ to be a step function and $g$ an exponential decay, the resulting convolution does not look like a function that is infinitely differentiable as the exponential decay $g$. What is wrong with my understanding?

Notation:
$C_c^{k}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of real functions k-times continuously differentiable with compact support.

How exactly is $f$ defined? How exactly is $g$ defined? what exactly is the mathematical expression for the convolution $f \ast g$? What do you mean by "does not look like a function that is $C^\infty$"?

Integration by parts (noting that $g$ is zero at the limits) and a touch of Leibnitz.

@jd27, f*g does not look differentiable at x=100. f is the plotted step function and g is exp(-ax).

@copper.hat, so you mean that the derivative exists in the weak sense?

@zooond It is differentiable in the usual sense (Frechet). Note that an exponential decay is certainly not an element of $C_c$.

The standard definition of Fourier convolution is $$f(x) * g(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x), g(y-x) , dx,,$$ the Fourier transform of $e^{-x}$ doesn't converge, $e^{-|x|}$ is continuous but not smooth at $x=0$, and $\theta(x), e^{-x}$ is discontinuous at $x=0$. So you need to clarify the definitions of your functions and also your definition of convolution.

Thanks all. I've understood my mistakes from your comments. I was assuming functions $f$ and $g$ defined only on $[0,\infty)$ (and not on the entire real line) and $g$ in my example is not compactly supported.

You still need to clarify your definition of the convolution integral. I've tried several different definitions and none of the results resemble your figure for $f * g$.

But perhaps the problem is that $g(x)=\theta(x), e^{-x}=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
e^{-x} & 0\le x \
0 & x<0 \
\end{array}\right.$ has a discontinuity at $x=0$.

The derivatives are in the strong sense. Indeed, let us show that $h:= f \ast g$ is once continuously differentiable, with the higher derivatives following the same argument. By the definition of convolution and the fact that $g$ is supported on $B(0,R):=\{|x|\le R\}$ for some $R>0$, and Hölder's inequality,
\begin{aligned}
\left|\frac{h(x+\delta)-h(x)}{\delta}-f\ast g'(x)\right| &= \left|\int_{B(0,R)} f(y) \left(\frac{(h(x-\delta-y)-h(x-y))}{\delta}-h'(x-y)\right)\,dy\right| \\
&\le \| f\|_{L^r} \left(\int_{B(0,R)} \left|\frac{(h(x-\delta-y)-h(x-y))}{\delta}-h'(x-y)\right|^{r/(r-1)}\,dr\right)^{1-1/r}\to 0
\end{aligned}
as $\delta \to 0$ by the dominated convergence theorem.
Thus for very $x$, $h'(x)=(f\ast g')(x)$. To check continuity, perform a similar estimate for $|f\ast g'(x+\delta) - f\ast g'(x)|$ using Hölder, dominated convergence and the compact support of $g'$. Iterating this shows that $h$ is $C^k(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
